# Seleccionar el valor maximo de un rango de celdas de otra hoja en google sheet

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando seleccionar el valor maxio de un rango de celdas de otra hoja en google sheets, pero no consigo dar con la formula, he provado distintas formulas:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("Enlace";"Resums per parc!max(D17:F17)")

=query(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace") "Select max(D,E,F) where B=TOTAL")

=query(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace") "Select max(Col4,Col5,Col6) where Col2=TOTAL")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería:

```
=MAX(IMPORTRANGE("<URL>"; "Resums per parc!D17:F17"))
```

[MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=es) para obtener el máximo. Y le pasas el intervalo, que será el resultado de `IMPORTRANGE`.

[IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=es) para importar de otro documento. Le pasas la URL de la hoja (`"<URL>"`), y luego el intervalo que quieres importar (`'Resums per parc'!D17:F17`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me queda asi `MAX(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace";"Resums per parc!D17:F17"))`

Comment: Me estaba complicando la vida con la query

Comment: Ah, pensaba que te referías a otra hoja en el mismo documento. No veía que te referías a otro documento. Me alegro de que lo tengas.

Comment: @IvánMontero deberías marcar que la respuesta es correcta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%C3%B3mo-usar-el-sitio/3762#3762

Comment: Lo se, se me fue de la cabeza